# How to assign a column in 2d-array to some repetitive range using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, repeat

I want to assign column values of 2d array to a repetitive range.
For example, range will be from **1** to **3**:

```
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
```

---

I have code:

```
width, height = 3, 6 
array2d = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

repRange = list(range(1,4)) #it is [1, 2, 3]

j = 0
for i in range(height):    
    array2d[i][0] = repRange[j]

    if j >= len(repRange)-1:
        j = 0
    j += 1

for row in array2d:
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
```

It fails. It started good, but in 2-nd repetition it failed.

---

What is wrong with logic? If there is a more simple approach, I hope you share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that when you get to the end of the `repRange` you are setting `j` to 1 instead of 0. That happens because `j += 1` is after the `if` statement; the test in the `if` statement also needs to be adjusted. Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
width, height = 3, 6 
array2d = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

repRange = list(range(1, 4)) #it is [1, 2, 3]

j = 0
for i in range(height):
    array2d[i][0] = repRange[j]

    j += 1
    if j >= len(repRange):
        j = 0

for row in array2d:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]
```

Here's a more compact version.

```
from itertools import cycle

width, height = 3, 6 
repRange = cycle(range(1, 4))
zeroes = [0] * (width - 1)
array2d = [[next(repRange)] + zeroes for y in range(height)]

for row in array2d:
    print(row)
```

And here's another:

```
from itertools import cycle

width, height = 3, 6 
zeroes = [0] * (width - 1)
array2d = [[v] + zeroes for _, v in zip(range(height), cycle(range(1, 4)))]

for row in array2d:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the standard library module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). The function `cycle` does what you want:

```
from itertools import cycle
width, height = 3, 6 
array2d = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
for l, i in zip(array2d, cycle([1,2,3])):
    l[0] = i
```